# Modified \listoflistings don´t show listings on Table of Listings . Package Minted

Tags: table-of-contents, minted, renewcommand

I have a problem using a redefined \listoflistings command to generate a table of listings for my thesis on a template based on a previous version of puthesis.cls. I need to generate a list of listings but the contens appear empty and I have no clear idea of what todo. Next appear the redefinition of the \listoflistings command:

```
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{
  \@@nonchapter{next}{LISTA DE CÓDIGOS FUENTE}{y}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Código\hfil Página}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Código\hfil Página}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font
    \@starttoc{lof}
  }
}
```

And there is a minimal tex file

```
\documentclass[ece,thesis,apacite]{puthesis}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{support-caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[style=base]{caption}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{datetime}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\monthnamespanish}[1][\month]{%
  \@orgargctr=#1\relax
  \ifcase\@orgargctr
    \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
    \or Enero%
    \or Febrero%
    \or Marzo%
    \or Abril%
    \or Mayo%
    \or Junio%
    \or Julio%
    \or Agosto%
    \or Septiembre%
    \or Octubre%
    \or Noviembre%
    \or Diciembre%
    \else \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lineno}
%linenumbers

\usepackage{listings}
% \lstset
% { %Formatting for code in appendix
%     language=Matlab,
%     basicstyle=\footnotesize,
%     numbers=left,
%     stepnumber=1,
%     showstringspaces=false,
%     tabsize=1,
%     breaklines=true,
%     breakatwhitespace=false,
% }

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Código}
\usemintedstyle{autumn}
\setminted{
    linenos=true,
    autogobble,
}
\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{stanli}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners = 8, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=.25cm, text width=3cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=black!50]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=.75cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=black!25]
\tikzstyle{proc_small} = [rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=black!25]
\tikzstyle{subsyst} = [rectangle, rounded corners =8, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=teal!50]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=black!7]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\setlength{\footskip}{84.3034pt}

\makeatletter % For spaces in paths
\patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thelisting}{\thechapter.\arabic{listing}}
\@addtoreset{listing}{chapter}
\makeatother


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-} m }{% [options for include pdf]{filename.pdf}
  \includepdf[%
    #1,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.7,
    ]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\secpdf{somO{1}m}{% [short title]{section title}[page specification]{filename.pdf} --- possibly starred
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=#4,
    pagecommand={%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \section*{#3}}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
          \section{#3}}{%
          \section[#2]{#3}}}},
    scale=.65,
    ]%
    {#5}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{OA}{AO}
\pudegree{I}{PP}{\monthname}{\the\year{}}
\majorprofs{\\D\\A}
\campus{M}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\chapter{P}
\label{Ch:ch}

\begin{longlisting}
    \inputminted[%
        breaklines,%
        breakafter=(,%
        frame=lines,%
        framesep=2mm,%
        baselinestretch=1.2,%
        bgcolor=LightGray,%
        fontsize=\footnotesize,%
        linenos%
    ]{HTML}{Raw-Data.txt}
    \caption{E}
    \label{listing:R}
\end{longlisting}

\end{document}
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have `puthesis.cls` nor `support-caption.sty`, so I cannot test. However, `lof` is usually not the file extension used by listings and minted but for figures. With the current version you can use `\ext@lstlisting`. See the original definition for more information.

Comment: Hello and thanks.  I am going to look the definition on the current version.